SSMS save results to file as CSV, output in multiple columns
I have a query with several columns, which I want to export as a CSV file, by using the save to file option in SSMS. I'm able to do that, but some rows will be exported to multiple columns in the .csv file. Most of the time this is in case of a text field, which can hold up to 100.000 characters. Does anyone know how to prevent this?
Save results to file as .csv

You probably shouldn't be using SSMS for exporting that data, if I am honest.
